# How to compute unit direction vector of a ray in 3D given its origin and angle with XZ and YZ planes?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I want to compute the unit direction vector for a ray in 3D. I have the coordinates of the starting point of the ray and angle the ray makes with the XZ and YZ plans where X is rightward, Y is upward and Z is forward direction. Any idea how should I go about it?

Comment: Use [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). For example, $$\begin{cases} x = \sin(\theta) \cos(\varphi) \\ y = \sin(\theta) \sin(\varphi) \\ z = \cos(\theta)\end{cases}$$where $\varphi$ is the angle between the ray and the $xz$ plane, and $\theta$ is the angle between the ray and the $z$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

Now that's a strange way to proceed. If I'm not mistaken, your basis isn't right-handed. If you have a choice in the matter, I'd recommend switching to something more conventional.

---

Say your unit direction vector is $\mathbf u=\left(x,y,z\right)^t$.
The unit normal vector to plane $XZ$ has coordinates
$\mathbf j=\left(0,1,0\right)^t$.
Let $\alpha_j$ be the angle between $\mathbf u$ and the $XZ$ plane.
Then 
$$
\langle \mathbf u,\ \mathbf j \rangle = y = \cos\left(\frac\pi 2-\alpha_j\right)
$$
Repeat for the other angle with plane $YZ$, you obtain $x$. You can deduce $z$ from the constraint that it is a unit vector.